# How to configure debug Flutter integration test on Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, automated-tests, flutterdriver

I can run this command in the terminal to execute integration test on real device

```
flutter drive --target=test_driver/app.dart
```

But I don't know how to create Run/Debug configuration on Android Studio so I can debug the test.
Please help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: Debugging an integration test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52024702/flutter-debugging-an-integration-test)

Comment: @ibhavikmakwana No, driver cannot run with Dart command line app anymore. Same as comment of gdbj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't require any special Run/Debug configuration on Android Studio to set breakpoints in an integration test using the [integration_test](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/packages/integration_test) package. This works the same for real devices, emulators, and Flutter Desktop.

#### Steps to reproduce

0. Make sure that your real device is connected:

```
$ flutter devices
3 connected devices:

XXXXXX (mobile) • XXXXXX     • android-arm64  • Android XX.XX (API XX)
Linux (desktop) • linux      • linux-x64      • Ubuntu 20.04.XX LTS XXX-generic
Chrome (web)    • chrome     • web-javascript • Google Chrome XXXXX
```

(See 
[Run Test Flutter Apps Directly on Real Android Device in Windows MAC Tutorial | flutter-examples.com](https://flutter-examples.com/run-test-flutter-apps-directly-on-real-android-device/))

1. Create a new Flutter project with the classic counter app:

```
flutter create debug_at_device_2
cd debug_at_device_2
flutter pub get
```

2. Open the project in Android Studio.
3. Set a breakpoint in the `_incrementCounter` method:

[image: breakpoint]

4. Add the `flutter_test` and `integration_test` packages as dev dependency in the `pubspec.yaml`:

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  integration_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

5. Update the packages again:

```
flutter pub get
```

6. Create a new directory `integration_test` and within that a file `example_test.dart` with the following contents:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:integration_test/integration_test.dart';
import 'package:debug_at_device/main.dart' as app;

void main() {
  IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  testWidgets("should increment counter", (WidgetTester tester) async {
    app.main();
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.add));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    expect(find.text('1'), findsOneWidget);

    await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.add));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    expect(find.text('2'), findsOneWidget);

    await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.add));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    expect(find.text('3'), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

7. Make sure that your real device is selected as the default device in the runner bar:

[image: default runner]

8. Make sure that the phone is unlocked (i.e. no screensaver)
9. Right-click on the run icon next to the `main` method in `example_test.dart` and then select the debug option from the context menu:

[image: start test debug]

10. Step through the code once the breakpoint gets hit:

[image: debugger]

#### Environment

I have tested it using:

- Flutter version 2.5.1
- Android Studio version 2020.3.1
- Flutter plugin version 60.1.2
- Ubuntu 20.04
- Android phone